# split a column in postgres on float and alphabets

Tags: regex, postgresql

How can I split the column **name** using regex in Postgres 12. I want output as below.

| name | Output | alternative output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abcd | {abcd} |  |
| abcd1234567efg | {abcd, 1234567, efg} |  |
| abcd1234567.89efg | {abcd, 1234567.89, efg} |  |
| abcd12efg34567hij | {abcd, 12, efg, 34567, hij} | {abcd, 12efg, 34567, hij} |
| abcd12efg34567.89hij | {abcd, 12, efg, 34567.89, hij} | {abcd, 12efg, 34567.89, hij} |

Right now using `SELECT (REGEXP_MATCH(name, '(?:(.*?)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(.*)){1,1}')) AS s`
which is fine with 2nd and 3rd row.

Any possible optimum solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try matching on the regex pattern `\d+(?:\.\d+)?|\D+`, which would match alternatively either numbers or groups of non digit characters:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_MATCHES(name, '\d+(?:\.\d+)?|\D+', 'g') AS s
FROM yourTable;
```

For an input of `abcd12efg34567.89hij`, the following elements would be matched:

```
s
{abcd}
{12}
{efg}
{34567.89}
{hij}
```